# VSCode - module.exports autocomplete in another file

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense, discord.js

Main JS file have this code:

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
    var cmd = require("./commands/test.js");
    cmd.run(bot, msg);
});
```

When i type "msg." in the event (code above) VSCode shows autocomplete suggestions like this: [Autocomplete in main js file (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zk18.png)

```
exports.run = function run(bot, msg) {

}
```

When i type "msg." in another file (code above) that is using module.exports the autocomplete suggestions doesn't show up: [Autocomplete in another file (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAzRg.png)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

I'm using VSCode Version: 1.32.1

Comment: You can JSDoc it and it will work again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSDocs to make the autocomplete again by doing:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

/**
 *
 * @param {Discord.Client} bot
 * @param {Discord.Message} msg
 */
exports.run = function run(bot, msg) {

}
```